# How to read file using different processes?

Tags: c, signals, fork, semaphore

I want to read a file using different processes but when i try that first created child read all file so other processes cannot read the file . For example i create 3 different process with 101,102 and 103 process ids.

> a read from = 101.
> b read from = 101.
> c read from = 101.
> d read from = 101.

But I wanted to read like that

> a read from = 101.
> b read from = 103.
> c read from = 102.
> d read from = 103.

I tried to solve it using semaphore and mutex but I couldn't do that. Could you help me, please?

```
int i=0, pid;
char buffer[100];

for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        sem_wait(&mutex); // sem_t mutex is global.           
        while(read(fd,&buffer[j],1) == 1){
            printf("%c read from = %d\n",buffer[j],getpid());
            j++;
        }
        sem_post(&mutex);
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: *I tried to solve it using semaphore and mutex*. You will certainly need some form of synchronisation using primitives like those. So please show your attempted code for that.

Comment: @kaylum I used sem_wait(&mutex) before while and after the while i used sam_post(&mutex).I am inexperienced with mutex and semaphore Unfortunately. I'm trying to learn.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67325763/edit) your post to update it with your attempted synchronisation code and give its exact behaviour.

Comment: *But i wanted to read like that*. And please clarify what you mean by "like that". What is the specific ordering you are trying to achieve? It's not clear just from the example.

Comment: I just want to read the file using all processes . I dont need a specific order .while one reads the whole file, others don't wait.

Comment: `while(read(fd,&buffer[j],1) == 1)` That loop is **inside** the critical section. If you want to only read one character and then give another process a chance you need to move the sem operations to be inside the loop so that it waits and locks for each character.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that even though each process has its own file descriptor, those file descriptors all share the same open file description ('descriptor' != 'description'), and the read position is stored in the file description, not the file descriptors.   Consequently, when any of the children reads the file, it moves the file pointer for all the children.

For more information about this, see the POSIX specifications for:

- [`open()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html)
- [`dup2()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)
- [`fork()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html)

No mutex or other similar gadget is going to fix this problem for you — at least, not on its own.  The easiest fix is to reopen the file in the child processes so that each child has a separate open file description as well as its own file descriptor.  Alternatively, each child will have to use a mutex, rewind the file, read the data, and release the mutex when done.  It's simpler to (re)open the file in the child processes.

Note that the mutex must be shared between processes for it to be relevant.  See the POSIX specification for [`pthread_mutexattr_setpshared()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_setpshared.html).  That is not set with the default mutex attribute values.

Comment: The OP appears to want to have a shared file position, such that each byte of the file is read by exactly one child.  So for that they can't reopen the file in each child as that would cause every child to read independently.

Comment: That's a possibility, @ChrisDodd, in which case, each child will need to read one character at a time, stopping when they come across a newline, space, or other non-numeric character.  They will also need to agree on how to coordinate so that the processes read in the order created.  One option is to have each child process create a new child after it reads its number.  That avoids lots of synchronization problems.

Answer (score -1):

You have two problems that prevent what you appear to want and will result in the entire file being read by (just) the first child

- the parent process waits for each child immediately after creating it, before forking any more children.  So after creating the first child, it will wait for that child to exit looping and creaing a second child.  To fix that, you need have two loops parent -- the first just creates children and the second waits for them:

  ```
    for (...) {
        if (fork() == 0) {
            // run the child
            exit(0); } }
    for (...)
        wait(NULL);  // wait for a child
  ```
- your reading loop is *inside* the sem_wait/sem_post.  So the first child will get the mutex, then proceed to read the entire file before releasing the mutex.  Subsequent children will not get the mutex until the file is fully read, so they'll see they're at the EOF and exit.  To fix this you need to move the sem_wait/sem_post calls inside the while loop:

  ```
    while (!done) {
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        if (read(...) == 1) { ...
        } else {
            done = true; }
        sem_post(&mutex); }
  ```

You might not even need the semaphore at all -- the kernel will synchronize reads between the different processes, so each byte will be read by exactly one child.  This would allow the children to proceed in parallel (processing the bytes) rather than only allowing one child at a time to run.

Of course, even with the above, one child may process many bytes before another child starts to run and process them, so if the processing is fast and there are few bytes, they might still all be consumed by the first child.